# API call keeps giving keyerror? discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to get this list of variables to work but it keeps giving me keyerror I have tried changing the variable etc but wont work

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    url = ('https://randomuser.me/api/')

    response = requests.get(url)
    title = response.json()["title"]
    first = response.json()["first"]
    last = response.json()["last"]
    number = response.json()["number"]
    street = response.json()["name"]
    city = response.json()["city"]
    state = response.json()["state"]
    postcode = response.json()["postcode"]
    country = response.json()["country"]
    phone = response.json()["phone"]
    age = response.json()["age"]
    dob = response.json()["date"]
    gender = response.json()["gender"]
    username = response.json()["username"]
    password = response.json()["password"]
    image = response.json()["large"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Fake Info Generator", description=f"**Name:** '{title}', '{first}' '{last}'\n**Address:** '{number}' '{street}', '{city}', '{state}', '{postcode}', '{country}'\n**Phone:** '{phone}'\n**Age:** '{age}', '{dob}'\n**Gender:** '{gender}'", color=18321)
    embed.set_footer(text="Random Info")                                                
    embed.set_image(url=f"'{image}'")
                                                           
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have tried things like changing the variables to thing like this but still wont work

```
title = response.json()["name"][0]["title"]
```

Comment: Can you please add your full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because that's now how JSON reading works.

You need to specify the entire "path" of the value you want to read. You can't just get `response.json()["title"]` because the response is not formatted like that.

The response JSON is formatted like the following:

```json
{
   "results":[
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Madame",
            "first":"Germaine",
            "last":"Rey"
         },
         ...
      }
   ],
   ...
}
```

To be able to read `title` you would need to read the content of the array `results` at index 0 *(because you only care of the first result)* then check the name and then finally the title, so it would look like that: `response.json()["results"][0]["name"]["title"]`